# R Scripts - Use Output Message as if condition

Tags: r

I am using the RGoogleAnalytics library to get all the data from my Google Analytics Account into R. However, complex queries deliver 0 results.

My code looks like:

```
  query.list <- Init(start.date = paste(c(lastmonth.startdate)),
                     end.date = paste(c(lastmonth.enddate)),
                     metrics = "ga:goalCompletionsAll",
                     dimensions = "ga:countryIsoCode,ga:yearMonth",
                     filters = "ga:goalCompletionsAll>0",
                     max.results = 10000,
                     table.id = sprintf("ga:%s", sites$profile.id[i]))

  # Create the Query Builder object so that the query parameters are validated
  ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list)

  # Extract the data and store it in a data-frame
  ga.countriesConversions1 <- GetReportData(ga.query, token)
```

Everything is inside a "for", and the script stops if one of the queries end in 0 results, because *GetReportData(ga.query, token)* cannot create a dataframe if there is no data.

I would like to know if there is a way use the warning message ("*Your query matched 0 results. Please verify your query using the Query Feed Explorer and re-run it*") fired by the library to the console, assign it to a variable and use this as an if condition. So I could create a dummy data.frame before the next function comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getReportData` is throwing an error, then you can try:

```
ga.countriesConversions1 <- try(GetReportData(ga.query, token), silent=TRUE)
if(inherits(ga.countriesConversions1, "try-error")) {
  warning(geterrmessage())
  ... error handling logic ...
}
```

Comment: Really intersting this try function. I didn't know that R had a proper function for that task. Let me see if I understand the logic: you try to excute GetReportData, and if this results in an error, R assign an invisible object class "try-error". You print the warning message at the console, but it is handled with the creation of a dummy data.frame. Isn't it?